# Can sino compare subjects?

Tags: conjunciones

[Duolingo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo) read me this sentence aloud and asked me to transcribe it:

> No veo hombres sino mujeres.

I misunderstood what was said and typed:

> No beben hombres sino mujeres.

I thought that that meant:

> Men do not drink, but women do.

Does it mean that? Can *sino* compare subjects, or only objects (*No quiero leche sino agua*) and clauses (*No corro sino camino*)?

Comment: A funny transcription, but a good question. :)

Comment: @Flimzy, I actually thought I'd heard "vev"/"beb" and assumed it must have been "beben" (and that I'd missed a quick "en"): in fact I'd misheard the final "o" as "v". Fwiw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

In fact, in [the DRAE's first example for the adverb *sino*](http://dle.rae.es/sino), you have the subject being contrasted: *No lo hizo Juan, sino Pedro*.

The only requirement is that the former element be negative, and the latter affirmative:

- No como, sino que bebo. (verb)
- No comí yo, sino tú. (subj)
- Comí una cena no muy grande, sino bastante pequeña. (adj)
- etc.

With clauses, remember that clauses really just act as placeholders for other elements (hence the different types are termed noun clauses — used where nouns go —, adjective clauses, etc.)

Comment: +1, and many thanks. Since you cite the RAE, I'll give you the checkmark (as you must be right `:-)`). If anyone has further info (e.g. on dialectal use) in another answer, that'd be great, too.

Comment: Also, technically, according to the DPD, when doing it with verbs, you should use *sino que*, although personally for short sentences like the above, it sounds weird to my ears (?*No como sino que bebo*).  Anything longer, *que* will be pretty much obligatory (from the DPD: *Prada no compraba la droga, sino que la vendía*)

Comment: At least here in Spain we always use *sino que* with verbs, regardless of the sentence length. When I read your answer, your first example sounded wrong to me immediately.

Comment: @Gorpik, I think it's because with a shorter sentence, in my mind I'm using _mas_, in which case there's no problem other than sounding, well, old, and poorly swapping with _sino_. I've updated my post.  (my bad)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Keep up the good work!